# How to tell what is trying to load a specific assembly?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2013

I have an MVC project that is failing once I deploy to Azure because it's trying to load an MVC4 assembly. I have upgraded the project to MVC5.

I am trying to find what has a dependency on the MVC4 dll.

How would I go about finding what is causing it to try and load the MVC4 dll?

Comment: How do you know it's failing because it's trying to load an MVC4 assembly and not something else? Is that from a log or something you can share in your question?

Comment: @ChristopherCurrens I enabled intellitrace and downloaded the logs. I get an error saying the role entrypoint could be not created due to the following exceptions: could not load file or assembly system.web.mvc version=4.0.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fusion logs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are the way to go for something like this.  Here's a [handy little blog](http://nemetht.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/fusion-log-assembly-binding-log/) that sums up the registry changes you need to add to capture the log on your instance.  Add this as part of a startup task.  In this post he also gives the location to the log viewer (on your local dev machine) that you can use to view the log.

Comment: Thanks @Rick Rainey. I finally got fusion logs going but it doesn't seem to pick up anything released to the system.web.mvc assembly, which is what shows up in the intellitrace logs when I download them.  
Any ideas where to go from here?

Comment: Do you see any logs at all or just not one for that assembly?  Also, did you set your taskType in the startup task where you enabled the logging to "Simple"?  If not, it could be that the error is already occurring before your logging is enabled.

@kwill has also provided very good guidance on tracking this down.  If you're seeing this in the intellitrace logs then you should be able to see which assembly (from the callstack) is referencing it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the same issue that you asked a week ago and received an answer for?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716911/web-role-fails-on-azure-after-upgrading-from-mvc4-to-mvc5/19733292#19733292

Rick's Fusion Logs option is also a great way to determine this.